# Regex - excluding characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a pattern that will ignore starting from Всего word and just will capture the number 2501,472 at the end -> Всего 191 Короб-шкаф вес БРУТТО 2501,472

Also, i am trying to include word change possibilities [^Короб-шкаф|Коробка] which is working fine in another pattern i have created

```
([^Всего]?[^\\d]*?[^Короб-шкаф|Коробка]\s*[^вес БРУТТО\\s*] \\d,]*)
```

Comment: Please, explain the issue you are facing.

Comment: What is your regex platform?

Comment: @anubhava Pattern

Comment: Use: `\\bВсего\\h+\\d+\\h+(?:Короб-шкаф|Коробка)\\h+вес\\h+БРУТТО\\h+([\\d,]+)` and use captured group #1 for your number.

Comment: @anubhava thank you generous man :) will observe what you did to know for later similar tasks

Comment: The [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) attempts to straighten out some common beginner misconceptions. You should read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this alternation regex that uses a capture group where we are capturing number that appears after a known pattern:

```
\\bВсего\\h+\\d+\\h+(?:Короб-шкаф|Коробка)\\h+вес\\h+БРУТТО\\h+([\\d,]+)
```

Then use captured group #1 for your number comprising digits and comma characters.

Comment: the pattern matches, but what i wanted to achieve is getting just the number at the end and ignoring whatever is left behind

Comment: Yes that's why suggestion of captured group is there in my answer. In Java you cannot have variable length lookbehind and also there is no `\K` like PCRE.